# Android: perfomance increasing while uploading file to server

Tags: java, android, intentservice

I need to upload the object to the server, with the photo in one of the fields. After the object was sent, I need to display it on the map. If the user enters the object, he needs to see the uploaded photo inside. I faced with the problem of bad performance of the photo sending - so the user needs to wait for a long time until the photo will be transferred. I went with 2 ways:

1) Straightforward approach. I tried to go with the `Base64` encoding and then send the file via the `Volley` library. The speed is unallowable - so the user needs to wait up to 4 seconds while the file is decoding to the string and sending to the server.

2) I went with the `Service` approach. So created the `IntentService` where uploaded the needed file:

```
    public class FileUploaderService extends IntentService{

    private static final String TAG = "FileUploaderService";

    /**
     * Creates an IntentService.  Invoked by your subclass's constructor.
     *
     * @param name Used to name the worker thread, important only for debugging.
     */
    public FileUploaderService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
    public FileUploaderService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent!=null){
            int id = intent.getIntExtra(Constants.BUNDLE_POST_UPLOAD_ID,0);
            if (id!=0){
                String url = "...";
                File image = new File(String.valueOf(intent.getStringExtra(Constants.BUNDLE_POST_UPLOAD_FILE)));
                BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.getAbsolutePath(),bmOptions);
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("image", Utils.convertBitmapToString(bitmap));
                Utils.sendVolleyRequestWithoutDialog(this, Request.Method.PUT, url, params, new VolleyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String stringObject) {

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(String error) {
                        Toast.makeText(FileUploaderService.this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That solves the problem of performance, but causes the problem, is when the user enters the object, there is no photo inside for a while.

So I need to find the solution which allows transferring the photo in a light way.

Comment: You might start by not converting to Base64. Adjust your server to support receiving the image in its natural binary format. Then, you might consider reworking your UI, such that the transfer process is not on the critical path for showing the photo. For example, you could superimpose something on the photo to indicate that it is still being uploaded.

Comment: Are you against showing it on the map before it's actually sent? If the upload succeeds most of the time, then you only display an error on the event it actually does.  A lot of apps will let the user continue on as if it's complete with some progress indication.

Comment: you could create a small payload and send it - than the user will see a preview. and than you will see the full image - whatsapp way :) also try cloudinary for that cause - makes it easier and faster

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not related to uploading. It's all about how your cache works. You just need some caching layer that will be used when loading a photo for an object. And when you're going to upload a photo, you just put it to the cache manually.